# Finding groups with the same name in Pandas?

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, grouping

I have two DataFrames that I split into groups by their months using:

```
grouped1 = data1[key].set_index('Time').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
grouped2 = data2[key].set_index('Time').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
```

`grouped2` might have more groups than `grouped1` or visa-versa. I would like to run stats on groups that share the same name between the grouped DataFrames.

For example, if `grouped1` has a group called `April`, and `grouped2` has a group called `April`, I want to run stats on those groups. I would like to cycle through all groups that share the same name.

How would I do this?
`

Comment: `.groups` will return the groups for a `groupby` object, you can then find the intersection of these and then get the specific group calling `.get_group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the groups from a `groupby` object using `.groups` this returns a dict, the keys are the group values, you can then find the common columns using `set` and `intersection` and then get the common groups using `.get_group`:

```
In [252]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','c','b','c'], 'data':np.random.randn(5)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','a','b','d'], 'data':np.random.randn(5)})
gp1 = df.groupby('id')
gp2 = df1.groupby('id')
print(gp1.groups)
print(gp2.groups)

{'b': [1, 3], 'a': [0], 'c': [2, 4]}
{'b': [3], 'a': [0, 1, 2], 'd': [4]}

In [ ]:    
common = set(gp1.groups.keys()).intersection(set(gp2.groups.keys()))
common

In [270]:
for gp in common:
    print('first:\n')
    print(gp1.get_group(gp).head())
    print('\nsecond: \n')
    print(gp2.get_group(gp).head())

first:

       data id
1 -0.252577  b
3  0.274945  b

second: 

       data id
3  1.521554  b
first:

       data id
0  0.142474  a

second: 

       data id
0  1.536180  a
1 -1.117422  a
2  1.490307  a
```